# Using web workers in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-worker

I'm trying to create a HTML5 Web Worker in phonegap, but phonegap doesn't allow me to load a local javascript file at runtime.
I get the following error:

```
var web_worker=new Worker('socket-worker.js')
undefined
file://socket-worker.jsFailed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Does anyone have a good suggestion on how I can work around this, and get the worker running?

Thanks!

Comment: there's absolutely no problem with PhoneGap loading files at runtime. Check your filepath, try with absolute path once.

Comment: @asprotte - were you able to use webworkers from phonegap?

Comment: Thank you SHANK. You were right, the problem was not with loading the file. @murtaza52 yes, the problem wasn't actually with the socket-worker.js file but due to the method i was importing the js library socket.io in my socket-worker.js using importScripts(). Instead of importing the socket.io script locally I had to load in it with an http request: importScripts('http://someaddress/socket.io.js')

Answer (score 9):

Haven't tried this yet but I believe we can run it using blob url. See it here ( http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers-bloburis )

**Update:** I've tried this already and it worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge Web Workers never works on local directory

> file://

it works on server side. For example instead of placing files at "file://" so the path should be

```
***> http://localhost/ or***
***> http://server_ip_address***
```

Hence Phonegap consists of HTML and Javascript which are at device directory hence web workers are not supported in Phonegap.

Comment: what about [http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html] and [http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/]?